# Google login API prompts user for more access than requested

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm making a sign in with Google option for my website. I'm using their OAuth 2 API.

In the forward request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` I specify the `scope` parameter to contain only `email`

However when the user is forwarded to `accounts.google.com` they are informed the following information will be shared with my site.

> To continue, Google will share your name, email address, language preference, and profile picture with mysite.com

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) on the `scope` parameter it defines `email` as

> See your primary Google Account email address

I do not wish to require a user to share anything with me beyond their email address. In fact I would be fine with not even having their email and just a unique key to identify them with. My goal is to offer a simpler way of allowing a user to create an account on my site, not read any of their Google account information.

Is there any way to collect only the user's email address (or even less information) when signing a user in with Google?